# Renaming last page using pyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm using the pyPDF2 library, with this script:

import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def pdf_splitter(path):
fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]

```
pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

    output_filename = '{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(
        fname, page+1)

    with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

    print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
```

if **name** == '**main**':
path = 'w9.pdf'
pdf_splitter(path)

This is just an example, it reads the original PDF with multiple pages on it and split into separated files. It adds the page number on the splited files:

Ex. Original PDF name: w9.pdf
Split into: w9_01_01.pdf,w9_01_02.pdf,w9_01_03.pdf

I need to rename the last splited pdf into w9_01_end.pdf instead of w9_01_03.pdf I know that with the getNumPages() you can get the total pages of the original pdf, but don't know how to detect the last one and name it different. Also with getPage you can get the current page too.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right the problem you might just add an `if` statement to check if you are creating the last page or not:

```
if page != pdf.getNumPages()-1: #for loop works from [0;x[
      output_filename = '{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(
          fname, page+1)
    else:
      output_filename = '{}_page_end.pdf'.format(
          fname)
```

Comment: Thanks zanga, I've tested your code but the final result is that always the _end file is generared. 

The "thing" is that, if the pdf has 3 pages, the script must split the 3 pages in separated files but the last file generated must end with the _end.pdf flag.

Comment: I've found a way, instead of creating and renaming, the first call to for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()): I added for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()-1): so always will generate the last page -1. Then I put this code below 
lastpage = pdf.getPage(pdf.getNumPages() - 1)
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(lastpage)

This get the last page of the array and generate the last pdf (03).